# Change HTML tag color in emacs web-emmet-helm mode

Tags: emacs, emmet, emacs-helm

I am trying to customize the text color for web-emmet-helm mode (I don't know which one is setting this particular syntax element) so that I can read it on a black terminal background. honestly I'm not too picky about my background color, but with the default settings I can't find any one color that allows me to see everything.

Does anyone know how to customize the syntax elements indicated in the screenshot? I've done a lot of google searching but probably don't know the right keywords to use. I don't know any lisp but can stick some lines into init.el if you provide them.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put the point (text cursor) where you want to know about the face (text style) and do `M-x describe-face`.  This will bring up a help window describing the face, including the name.  Then you can do `M-x customize-face`, enter the face name, change the fg color, bg color, and whatever else, and save it.  Use `M-x list-colors-display` to see all the named colors, or use hex RGB to set the color.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following block to init.el does the trick. The face names are all listed at http://web-mode.org in the Customization section.

```
(defun pk-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (set-face-attribute 'web-mode-html-tag-bracket-face nil :foreground "White")
  (set-face-attribute 'web-mode-html-tag-face nil :foreground "Yellow")
  )
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'pk-web-mode-hook)
```